# How many friends for birthday party every weekend?

Tags: probability

A friend claims that he is invited to a birthday party every weekend.

I know he needs to have at least 52 friends for that, but what is the "realistic" amount of friends that chances are 100% for beeing invited every weekend

Comment: 'Realistic' is a very vague definition

Comment: If your friend is friends with every human being not born from January 1st to January 7th, and friends with no one born from January 1st to January 7th, he won't be invited to a party every weekend, and he would have a lot of friends.

Comment: The difficulty is your use of "realistic" and "100% probability" in the same problem statement.  In a world where "one-in-a-billion accidents" can happen, you need to state what level of probability you would be happy with:  99% ?  99.9% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is on $100\%$ guarantee, but you can pick any lower chance and find a number of friends.  Say we want a $50\%$ chance that he gets invited every weekend of the year.  If you have a favorite number, you can follow this through.  We need the probability $p$ of getting invited any given weekend to satisfy $p^{52}=\frac 12$, which gives $p = \left(\frac 12 \right)^{\frac 1{52}}\approx 0.98676$.  Now with $n$ friends, the chance of getting an invitation on a given weekend is $1-(1-\frac 1{52})^n$, so we want $$1-\left(1-\frac 1{52}\right)^n= \left(\frac 12 \right)^{\frac 1{52}}\\1-\left(\frac 12 \right)^{\frac 1{52}}=\left(1-\frac 1{52}\right)^n\\ \frac{\log\left(1-\left(\frac 12 \right)^{\frac 1{52}}\right)}{\log\frac {51}{52}}=n\\ n \approx 223 $$  This seems reasonable.  On average he will get about  $4.288$ invitations per weekend.  Using a Poisson model, that says the chance of a miss on a given weekend is one in $\boxed{73}$

Comment: Just to illustrate the "never a certainty" aspect of this, to raise the odds to 90% for weekly invitations, you need 320 friends; having 441 friends (_more than one_ for every day of the year) brings the probability to 99% .  (To complicate this a bit further, the assumption here is that birthdays are distributed in a _uniform_ random fashion.  In actuality, there is a slight seasonal variation in when people are born, with the "peak" during the late summer months.)